# How to fetch the Cost/Month for the VMSize using AZ Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, disk

I need to fetch the Cost/Month for the VMSize using AZ Powershell.

In the Azure Portal, We can get all the details of Cost/Month,IOPS,vCPU,RAM,etc... when we select the VMSize.
Using cmdlet "Get-AZVMSize -Location "" we get only VMSizeName, no.ofCores,MemoryinMB,MaxDataDiskCount,OSDiskSizeinMB,ResourceDiskSizeinMB only.

The Cost is not coming out. Any AZ Powershell cmdlet which can provide me the Cost/Month for the VMSize based on location?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such cmdlet Out of Box for cost as such. Here is the PowerShell script that uses `Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail` to get cost of a VM:

```
 $costTotal=0
 $RGName ="RGNAME" 
 $StartDay="2019-12-01"
 $EndDay="2019-12-06"
 $VMName="vm1"
 $Consumption = Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail -ResourceGroup $RGName -StartDate 
 $StartDay -EndDate $EndDay -InstanceName $VMName 
    
 $Costs = $Consumption.PretaxCost
    
 foreach ($Cost in $Costs) { $CostTotal += $Cost}
    
 $CostTotal
```